# ¿Puedo renderizar dos componentes en la misma Route, utilizando react-router-dom?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

App.js

```
import SideBar from './components/SideBar/SideBar';
import MainContent from './components/MainContent/MainContent';
import Gogers from './components/Gogers/TopGogers';
import {Route, Routes} from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className='my-app'>
      <div className='content'>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<SideBar/>}/>
          <Route path="/dasboard" element={<MainContent />} />
          <Route path="/gogers" element ={<Gogers />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Requiero que en la **Route** con `path="/"` se me rendericen los componentes `SideBar` y `MainContent`. ¿Es esto posible?

Ya conseguí renderizar `SideBar`, pero no he podido hacer que el `MainContent` se renderice en la misma route raiz...

Comment: Una buena practica es renderizar psginas (no es mas que un componente) y dentro de ella renderizar los componentes que desees. Porque necesitas hacerlo en la forma que dices?